# Remove dot after line in ol

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I found many answers, but none of them worked in my case. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/ggdkpbk7/). How to remove the dots?

Here is the basis of all of my attempts:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggdkpbk7/1/)***

Change the line in jQuery mobile css where it says:

```
content: counter(listnumbering) ".";
```

to

```
content: counter(listnumbering);
```

or simply override the UI mobile styles adding:

```
ol.ui-listview>li>.ui-btn:first-child:before,
ol.ui-listview>li.ui-li-static:before,
ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>label:before,
ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>.ui-controlgroup-label:before{
    content: counter(listnumbering) !important;
}
```

Comment: But I download the scripts everytime I run my code, so I can't do that. I should apply what you are saying with some other way, maybe with keyword important.

Comment: @gsamaras yes exactly.

Comment: @gsamaras, my review led to the same answer and it works in testing. Does it not work for you?